# Spring boot unable to create database schema and insert values on load at MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm unable to get spring boot to automatically load my database schema when I start it up. I am using MySQL as an external DB.  Please find below the code

application properties

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/carsdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
```

Application.java

```
package com.truckla.cars;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class CarsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CarsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Model entity

```
package com.truckla.cars.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import javax.persistence.*;

@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", initialValue=4, allocationSize=100)
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer id;
    String manufacturer;
    String model;
    Integer build;

    public Car() {
    }

    public Car(Integer id, String manufacturer, String model, Integer build) {
        this.id = id;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.model = model;
        this.build = build;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public int getBuild() {
        return build;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void setBuild(Integer build) {
        this.build = build;
    }
}
```

schema.sql

```
CREATE TABLE cars (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
  manufacturer VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  model VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  build YEAR DEFAULT NULL
);
```

data.sql

```
INSERT INTO cars (manufacturer, model, build) VALUES
  ('Ford', 'Model T', 1927),
  ('Tesla', 'Model 3', 2017),
  ('Tesla', 'Cybertruck', 2019);
```

Any ideas what am i doing wrong and what i should change in order to get it work?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with below properties in application-properties file?

spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

spring.sql.init.mode=always

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts

Comment: Nope nothing changed..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try running with the following properties.

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```